# stripe.js not reporting error when Stripe object creation fails

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have a very intermittent failure where my JavaScript fails to produce a Stripe `PaymentElement`, which results in the client not getting a payment form. I can't reliably reproduce this, but I get exactly the same effect if I supply an invalid key when calling `Stripe(publishableKey)`. I'm running test mode, not live.

The problem is that I can't persuade the call to `Stripe` to report an error if I deliberately give it the wrong key. The code below just carries on logging "stripe: key Ok" in the server logs, even when the key is wrong and the subsequent attempt to create a `paymentElement` fails. Can anyone give me any pointers on how to detect an error here? I've had this for a couple of weeks and I'm completely out of ideas. In this app, the client carries out an Ajax request to get the key from the server, and the code below is the callback function when the key is returned:

```
   stripeFuncs.setPKey = function(pkey) {
      serverLog(1, "stripe: received key (" + pkey + ")");  // record a message on the server
      try {
         stripe = Stripe(pkey);
      } catch(e) {
         // nothing is thrown: this never happens
         modalAlert("Error", "Cannot initialise Stripe ('" + e.message + "').");
         return;
      }
      serverLog(1, "stripe: key Ok");
   };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loaderror` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_loaderror#element_on_loaderror-event) can catch the wrong key or any error upon loading. ie.

```
paymentElement.on('loaderror',function (ev){
  console.log(ev.elementType);
  console.log(ev.error);
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually checking for `loaderror`, but only later when I attempt to create the `paymentElement`. Do you think you can't catch errors *before* creating the `paymentElement`? The problem with 'late' detection is that the payment request has already been logged at Stripe.

Comment: The loaderror is catched by calling the `paymentElement` itself, so I don't think you can do it before even initializing `paymentElement`